# Laravel - Unable to fetch data in blade from Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-8

I want to fetch data from a view in Oracle, SQL query in controller is as follows :

```
$cnx = DB::connection('oracle');
$outs = $cnx->select("SELECT client FROM M_CLIENT 
                      WHERE INSTR(STATUS, 'OUT')>0 
                      AND DPTID=:dptid",['dptid'=>$dptId[0]->dptid]);
```

and the return : `return view('clients.home', compact('outs'));`

But if I loop though **outs** in controller

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($outs); $i++) { 
            print_r($outs[$i]->client );
            echo '<br/>';
        }
```

I get the list of clients as wanted

While in blade, I tried :

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
   <tr>
     <td> {{ $outs[$i]['client'] }} </td>
   </tr>
@endfor
```

and :

```
@foreach($outs as $out)
   <tr>
     <td> {{ $out['client'] }} </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

and :

```
@foreach($outs as $out)
   <tr>
     <td> {{ $out->client }} </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

I get a blank page with 500 server error.

**PS:** The output of `dd($outs)` is :

```
array:7 [▼
0 => {#1290 ▼
    +"client": "Client1: OUT"
  }..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Problem fixed***

Forgot about `/storage/logs/laravel.log` where log errors are written.. Turned out some code wrapped in comment in blade was being executed, and The **right** code in blade is

```
@foreach($outs as $out)
   <tr>
     <td> {{ $out->client }} </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```